# Get id's when click (ANDROID)

Tags: android, layout, user-input

Simple question, i have this code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/insideLinearLayout1"
        ...
        <TextField>
          android:text='beforeClick'
          ...

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="updateExpression"
            ...


   </Linear Layout 

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/insideLinearLayout2"
        ...

          <TextField>
          android:text='beforeClick'
          ...
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="updateExpression"
            ...


   </Linear Layout 

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The idea, is to change the textField text property, when clicking the button on the same layout!

Ok for 2 is easy, just need the reference of each button and each textfield and change use the get and set method!
But i want to add more layouts dynamically, and grab each one's reference would be a hard task.

So two **questions :**

> 1. `How can i grab the id of the Linear layout, that have the clicked button?`
>
>    I want to handle the 'insideLinearLayout(1 or 2 depending on the clicked button)'id in the 'updateExpression'!
> 2. `How can i add more layouts with the same widgets as the ones created manually?`

Thank you in advance. 
Best of codings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Your onClick function is passed the view that was clicked.  Every view has a getParent() function.  You can use it to get the LinearLayout, then get the id.

2)Create them with the new keyword then add them to the parent layout.  For something like this I would probably make a custom compund view holding everything you want to instantiate at once, so you can treat the entire set of widgets as one.

Comment: public void updateExpression(View v){
  
  View parentLayout = (View)v.getParent();
  int id = parentLayout.getId();
  
  Log.v("NAME",String.valueOf(id));

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. 
How would i do the second step? Can i grab a reference of the one already created, create instance and change some parameters?

Comment: You'd do TextView newView = new TextView(activity) to create one.  Then change whatever values you want.  Similarly for other view types.